# Problem converting a byte array into datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization

In my aspx page I have a HTML inputfile type which allows user to browse for a spreadsheet.Once the user choses the file to upload I want to read the content of the spreadsheet and store the content into mysql database table.

I am using the following code to read the content of the uploaded file and convert it into a datatable in order into insert it into database table.

```
if (filMyFile.PostedFile != null)
        {
            // Get a reference to PostedFile object
            HttpPostedFile myFile = filMyFile.PostedFile;

            // Get size of uploaded file
            int nFileLen = myFile.ContentLength;

            // make sure the size of the file is > 0
            if (nFileLen > 0)
            {
                // Allocate a buffer for reading of the file
                byte[] myData = new byte[nFileLen];

                // Read uploaded file from the Stream
                myFile.InputStream.Read(myData, 0, nFileLen);

                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

               MemoryStream st = new MemoryStream(myData);
               st.Position = 0;
               System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatter formatter = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter();
               dt=(DataTable)formatter.Deserialize(st);
}
}
```

But I am getting the following error when I am trying to deserialise the byte array into datatable.

**Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization.**

Could someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

I've also tried converting the bytearray into string ,then converting the string back to byte array and convert into datatable.That is also throwing the same error.

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of file are you uploading?

Comment: I am uploading an excel sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes you think that you can deserialize a spreadsheet into a datatable? You can most definitely not! All you need to do is to save the byte[] (`myData`) to a `VARBINARY` column in an appropriate table in your mysql database.

**EDIT**

You can do something along these lines:

Suppose you have a mysql table:

```
create table MyTable(
   Id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT
   SpreadSheet BLOB 
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

You could use the following code to insert the uploaded file into the table:

```
string strConn="PROVIDER=MySQLProv;SERVER=192.168.1.8;DB= test;UID=test;PWD=;PORT=;";
OleDbConnection objConn;
objConn=new OleDbConnection (strConn);
objConn.Open();
string sql="INSERT INTO MyTable (SpreadSheet) VALUES(?)";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql,objConn);
OleDbParameter param = new OleDbParameter ("@image",OleDbType.Binary );
param.Value = myData;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
objConn.Close ();
```

Comment: actually I want to store the data from spreadsheet as it is(like rows and columns) in mysql table.so I am trying to deserialize the byte array into datatable from which I will insert the data using mysql query.Is it not possible to convert the byte array (mydata) to a datatable?

Comment: @Kranthi. No, not at all. I don't think you completely understand what serialization/deserialization does. Try and read up on it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9(VS.71).aspx
As I said before, all you need to do is insert the bytes into the database. I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining  with an example @klausbyskov.Actually my requirement is that I should allow a user to browse for a spreadsheet then read the content of the file and create a table in the database and insert all the data(rows and columns) that are present in the spreadsheet into the table.From your posts I think I am following the wrong approach to achieve my requirement.Please correct me.